# How does nuget/msbuild copy the package's lib content to the output directory - rules?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, packagereference

**TL;DR**: What are the exact rules for *consuming* the `lib` directory inside of a nuget package?

When consuming a NuGet package from Visual Studio in my C# .NET SDK projects, the contents of the packages `lib` folder are copied to the output directory.

There are certain rules governing the layout of the lib folder in the released package, e.g. `lib/TxM/*` that the files need to be grouped by [Target Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks) and also I find that `*.resources.dll` are treated specially.

There are [hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/select-assemblies-referenced-by-projects#packagereference-support) scattered in various NuGet doc topics wrt. the layout of this folder, and what would then be copied (by msbuild/nuget) to the projects output folder and what would then be referenced from the project itself ("linked").

**However**, I cannot find a proper documentation for the rules governing the consumption of the files from the nupckg content from Visual Studio.

Specifically I seem to observe, and I think I've seen it mentioned, that only files directly at `lib/TxM/*.*` will be referenced and any subfolders ignored -- what are the exact rules governing this?

---

#### Listing the snippets I found so far

The following is a list of info I found so far on this.

A specific gem I want to highlight is *"For many packages the lib works the same way it does in NuGet 2.x,"* ... if anyone could tell me what the rules were/are, that'd be much appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/select-assemblies-referenced-by-projects#packagereference-support :

> ... uses PackageReference, NuGet selects compile and runtime assets
> ...
>
> Compile assets prefer `ref/<tfm>/*.dll` (for example
> `ref/net6.0/*.dll`), but if that does not exist, then it will fall
> back to `lib/<tfm>/*.dll` (for example `lib/net6.0/*.dll`).
>
> Runtime assets prefer `runtimes/<rid>/lib/<tfm>/*.dll`... fall back to
> `lib/<tfm>/*.dll`

https://github.com/NuGet/docs.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/9c6c26ea385deaad4bd92a7a88d170796352bab1/docs/archive/project-json-and-uwp.md#L65 :

> `Lib` : For many packages the lib works the same way it does in NuGet
> 2.x, but with expanded options for what names can be used inside it and better logic for picking the correct sub-folder when consuming
> packages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files :

> If you follow the conventions described in Creating a Package, you do
> not have to explicitly specify a list of files in the .nuspec file.
> ...
>
> When a package is installed into a project, NuGet automatically adds
> assembly references to the package's DLLs, excluding those that are
> named `.resources.dll` because they are assumed to be localized
> satellite assemblies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory :

> `lib/{tfm}` : Assembly (.dll), documentation (.xml), and symbol (.pdb)
> files for the given Target Framework Moniker (TFM)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#framework-version-folder-structure :

> ... you always make subfolders under `lib` using different
> case-sensitive framework names ...
>
> ... You should never have a version of the library that is not
> specific to a framework and placed directly in the root lib folder.
> ...
>
> ... To easily include all these files when building the package, use a
> recursive `**` wildcard in the `<files>` section of your `.nuspec`:
>
> ```
> <file src="lib\**" target="lib/{framework name}[{version}]" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From the description, you have already found many related documents. Those should be enough to explain many things you want.

> A specific gem I want to highlight is "For many packages the lib works
> the same way it does in NuGet 2.x,"

For this thing you want to know, you can take a look of these official documents:

[Group dependencies by target frameworks of Nuget 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.0#group-dependencies-by-target-frameworks)

And

[Grouping content files and PowerShell scripts by target framework of Nuget 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.0#grouping-content-files-and-powershell-scripts-by-target-framework)

Comment: Unfortunately, so far I haven't found anything in the release notes you link to that would be of help. But I guess the release notes are a useful tip to find more info.